# Select query with multiple parameterized in-clauses

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, razor-2

I have a form with 2 dropdown lists and 3 checkbox sections that users select from to search the database. Since all of the tables are small, I'd like to use a single SELECT statement to return the results. I found an extension on mikesdotnetting that works great with a single IN clause

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebMatrix.Data;
using System.Linq;

public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> QueryIn(this Database db, string commandText, string values)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
        throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or an empty string", "values");
    var temp = values.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var temp2 = values.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var temp3 = values.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var parms = temp.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
    var parms2 = temp2.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
    var parms3 = temp3.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
    var inclause = string.Join(",", parms, parms2, parms3);
    return db.Query(string.Format(commandText, inclause), temp, temp2, temp3);
}

public static int ExecuteIn(this Database db, string commandText, string values)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
        throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or an empty string", "values");
    var temp = values.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var parms = temp.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
    var inclause = string.Join(",", parms);
    return db.Execute(string.Format(commandText, inclause), temp);
}
 }
```

Here is the page code showing how I envision the query:

```
var gender = Request["genderSvd"];
var person = Request["chkPerson"];
var spec = Request["chkSpec"];
var county = Request["ctyLoc"];
var crim = Request["chkCrim"];

    var db = Database.Open("HBDatabase");
    var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tblProgram.* FROM lnkPrgPersonSvd INNER JOIN tblProgram ON lnkPrgPersonSvd.prgId = tblProgram.prgId";
    sql += "INNER JOIN lnkPrgSpecial ON tblProgram.prgId = lnkPrgSpecial.prgId INNER JOIN tblProgram.prgId = lnkPrgCriminal.prgId ";
    sql += "WHERE (lnkPrgPersonSvd.personId IN ({0})) AND (lnkPrgSpecial.specId IN ({1})) AND tblProgram.prgGenderSvdId = @2 ";
    sql += "AND tblProgram.prgCounty = @3 AND (lnkPrgCriminal.criminalId IN ({4}))";

    var prgList = db.QueryIn(sql, person, spec, gender, county, crim);
```

That, obviously, doesn't work, because the extension cannot take that many arguments. I'm looking for a way to modify the class to allow for the additional parameters so that the query can run with just the one execution. This may not be possible.

Also, I did find several threads that dealt with handling a single parameterized in clause, but no real mention of multiples with variable lists.

I am not adept with stored procedures or writing my own classes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was pointed to a partial solution to this issue at [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1821264.aspx/1). This builds the query correctly, but I'm still having issues passing the checkbox values back in as query parameters (the temp section of the code).